# Modify CSS rule if another DOM element is present

Tags: css

I am NOT a webdev, just trying to fix some already broken CSS. What I'm asking may not be possible.

I'm dealing with a CMS that has a special set of pages that has a column (that isn't present on other pages).  This column is identified with a specific ID that won't appear on the other pages.

My question is whether I can have an optional CSS rule that affects a different element (A button that has an absolute position on the page) if the column is present or not.  I.e. the button draws at 20 pixels from the right if the column isn't there but draws 150 pixels if the column is there.  Is this possible.

FYI due to the limitations of the CMS I can't just have a different stylesheet for these pages, I have to use the same shared sheet as for other pages.

For reference this is the div that I would want to modify if the ID appears.

```
div.join {
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: is your button is inside outer div(having ID)?

Comment: you might want to add additional info to your question, in short, the structure of your page may or may not lend itself to what you are trying to achieve. There may be CSS selectors and / or hacks that can be used to help you depending on structure.

Answer (score -1):

You can add parent class name or Parent id to apply css like this.

**Using Class**

```
.my_parent_class div.join {
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

**Using Id**

```
#my_parent_class div.join {
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: So if my columns ID is "special_column_id", then I can make a rule saying if special_column_id is present, then div.join is defined like this.  I assume I'll need to mark it important to override the existing definition of div.join?

Comment: This will only work if your button is inside #my_parent_class

Comment: Yes, you have to mark important to override the existing definition of div.join.  like this way  #my_parent_class div.join { position:  absolute !important;}

Comment: As per my question, the div is an absolute element on the page.  I want to modify the behaviour IF a special element is present in the DOM (e.g. div special_column_id).

Comment: In the CSS there is no way to check element is exist or not in dom. so, You can set a unique class for special_column_id and set CSS for that element and if you want check element to exist in dom then you can check it via javascript.

Comment: @Vishal, that is my question.  If you answer it like so I can give you the answer.  Essentially CSS doesn't allow you to do this, I'd have to use a javascript to detect the column then move the button essentially, OR modify my CSS so that if the column appears the button's position is relative to the right of the column that will move.